# Run ubuntu 11.04 after full installation

Tags: installation, usb, guest-os

I have did a full installation of Ubuntu 11.04 on a 8GB flash drive and I want to run it as a guest OS on a Windows 7 host computer. Can anyone provide a guide on how I can run it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Booting From the Flash Drive

You can try and boot from the flash drive. Every BIOS is different, but most of them will have a message like “Press F12 for the Boot Menu”, which is highly suggested. The boot menu will allow you to select the USB drive as the boot device.